# How do I separate my Typeorm data source config into a separate variable?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, datasource, typeorm

I'm using NestJS 10 and TypeORM 0.3.17.  I have this src/config/data-source.ts file ...

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

dotenvExpand.expand(dotenv.config());

export default new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/database/migrations/*.js'],
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
 });
```

I would like to separate the argument as a variable so that I can export it for use in my src/config/typeorm.ts file, which has duplicate code ...

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions,
  TypeOrmModuleOptions,
} from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const typeOrmAsyncConfig: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: async (): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
      username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      synchronize: false,
      logging: true,
    };
  },
};

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10),
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
    migrations: ['dist/migrations/**/*.js'],
    extra: {
      charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    },
    logging: true,
};
```

but when I attempt to refactor my src/config/data-source.ts file like so

```
export const dsConfig = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
    migrations: ['dist/database/migrations/*.js'],
    extra: {
      charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    },
   };

export default new DataSource(dsConfig);
```

I get the error

```
    Argument of type '{ type: string; host: string; port: number; database: string; username: string; password: string; entities: string[]; migrations: string[]; extra: { charset: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataSourceOptions'.
  Type '{ type: string; host: string; port: number; database: string; username: string; password: string; entities: string[]; migrations: string[]; extra: { charset: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AuroraMysqlConnectionOptions': region, secretArn, resourceArn
```

on the line "export default new DataSource(dsConfig);".  How do I properly refactor my data source configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see around [my repo](https://github.com/HaiAlison/boiler-plate-nestjs/blob/main/src/utils/config/database/config.service.ts) to separate config data source file
in app.module.ts file:

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(typeOrmAsyncConfig),
```

your config file:

```
const config: ConfigService = new ConfigService();
const dbConfig = {
type: 'postgres' as const,
  host: config.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST'),
  port: config.get<number>('DATABASE_PORT'),
  database: config.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME'),
  username: config.get<string>('DATABASE_USER'),
  password: config.get<string>('DATABASE_PASS'),
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.{ts,js}'],
  migrationsRun: true,
  migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations',
  synchronize: false,
  ssl: config.get('SSL_MODE', false),
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
  logging: true,
}

export const typeOrmAsyncConfig: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
  useFactory: async (): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => {
    return dbConfig;
  },
};
export default new DataSource(dbConfig);
```

your package.json file:

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d src/utils/config/database/config.service.ts",
    "migration:generate": "npm run build && npm run typeorm -- migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
    "migration:create": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:create ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
```

and your command will be like this below:

```
npm run migration:generate --name=<your_migration_name> //auto generate migration with entities
npm run migration:create --name=<your_migration_name> //create empty migration file
npm run migration:revert    //revert your last migration
npm run migration:run // in case you set `migrationsRun: false` in your config and run it manually
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is the "//...your config" where I would put my PostGres db connection settings?

Comment: yes, that place you will put your all config of datasource

Comment: I've edited my config, check it out.

Comment: Evidently my problem was that I had "type: 'postgres'" instead of "type: 'postgres' as const", which cured the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

To work with TypeORM and NestJS, I have adopted a new strategy which is pretty simple.
Use named exports to your DataSource instance, create a DatabaseService that implements TypeormOptionsFactory from @nestjs/typeorm and return your dataSource options within createTypeormOptions method.

```
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
    public createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        return dataSource.options;
    }
}
```

Afterwards, create a DatabaseModule, setup TypeOrmModule with `.forRootAsync` and make use of `dataSourceFactory` to initialize your DataSource instance.

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            useClass: DatabaseService,
            dataSourceFactory: async (
                options?: DataSourceOptions,
            ): Promise<DataSource> => {
                if (!options) {
                    throw new Error('No DataSource options provided');
                }

                return dataSource.initialize();
            },
        }),
    ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

I have this [github repository](https://github.com/matheustrres/payment-service-provider/tree/main/src/infra/database) which you can see how it works.

Comment: I'm not understanding how this helps me solve my current error.

Comment: @Dave doing the way I mentioned, you won't need to separate things over, createTypeOrmOptions will handle it. By the way, you can also just use dataSource.options in any other parts of your application.

Comment: I need my data-source.ts file because in my package.json, I'm required to pass a data source for certain scripts, e.g. '"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run -d dist/config/data-source.js"'

Comment: Hey @Dave did you find a solution to this? If you did would help me if you could point me in that direction. Have been searching the internet for this & cant find anything. Thanks!